# how to validate a polymorphic field association in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, simple-form, polymorphic-associations

Here is the question, I have a customer and address model as follows:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end
```

I have a customer form with the render address information, for example:

```
# customers/form   
  = f.input :name
  ...
  # render form/address
  = f.input :apto
  = f.input :city
  = f.input :references
```

What I am looking for is to validate the address fields in the customer form, in such a way that if the user does not enter any value then it prevents its creation or update

pdd: The address entity is polymorphic and I can use it in any relationship. But I don't know how to validate its fields when I use it in the form of other relations

If you could help me I would be grateful and thank you very much for taking the time to read me.

**UPDATE 22/12/2022**

I would like to specifically validate the **address fields** (apto, city, reference) that are in **customers** only and not in others entities

Since any other entity can use address and in those entities the fields must be without validation

many thanks to @max who recommended validates_associates, however it validates all addresses

Comment: You would use [`validates_associated`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) - the association being polymorphic is irrelevant as it works with any kind of association.

Comment: Thank you @max but It validates the fields that are related to address and only I only look for it to validate the address fields within the client 

client -> address (validate field as city, reference, apto)
user -> address (not validate field)
articles -> address (not validate field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for:

```ruby
validate :validate_fields, if: -> { addressable_type == 'Customer' }
```

Comment: It helped me @saviu-u, thank you very much for your time and for your help :D.

pdd: I mixed the max solution "validates_associated" with the addressable_type to validate specific fields